# How to get base64 encoded value from URL parameters and place it in an input field with JavaScript

Tags: url, parameters, base64

I want to use (base64 encoded key) as URL parameter

like:
mydomain.com/?key=cHVyY2hhc2VwcmljZT0zNCQ=

that returns: purchaseprice=34$

I read [How to get base64 encoded...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607266/how-to-get-base64-encoded-value-from-url-in-javascript-variable) but it did not help.

here is my working code without base64:

```html
<input type="text" id="price" />
<script>
const url = new URL(window.location);
document.querySelector('#price').value = url.searchParams.get('purchaseprice');
</script>
```

[and in Codepen](https://codepen.io/shahabarvin/pen/JmzyZq?purchaseprice=2346)

Comment: Do you expect the return value of `purchaseprice` to be base64 encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to cptcoathanger

i did it With this Simple code.

```js
var fdurl = new URL(window.location);
var fdunc = fdurl.searchParams.get('key');
var url = "https://codepen.io/shahabarvin/pen/JmzyZq?" + window.atob(fdunc); 
document.querySelector('#price').value = new URL(url).searchParams.get("purchaseprice");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="price" />
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shahabarvin/pen/JmzyZq?key=cHVyY2hhc2VwcmljZT0zNCQ=)

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting the return value of `purchaseprice` to be base64 encoded then you'll need to use the `atob()` function:

```
<input type="text" id="price" />
<script>
const url = new URL(window.location);
document.querySelector('#price').value = atob(url.searchParams.get('purchaseprice'));
</script>
```

Details here: [Base64 Encoding / Decoding in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

Example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyLRpV?purchaseprice=VGVzdA==)